# Running CasperJS from cron

Tags: casperjs

So, I'm trying to run casperJS as a cron job on my server, this is the crontab:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/casperjs /var/www/javascript/uat/prime.sh 2>&1
```

This is prime.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

export PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs
/usr/local/bin/casperjs /var/www/javascript/uat/prime.js 2>&1
```

I've also added the export to the users' .bash_profile, but cron emails me with

```
Fatal: [Errno 2] No such file or directory; did you install phantomjs?
```

Not sure what else to do! Any advice?

Answer (score 12):

Calling a `.sh` with casperjs which only runs `.js` or `.coffee` files won't fork for sure. I think you can setup your cronjob more directly like this:

```
* * * * * PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/casperjs /var/www/javascript/uat/prime.js 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks NiKo, this worked for me. Thus, IMO, @Mike should mark it as an answer.

Comment: Work for me too. what is the difference between PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs in command line, and in .bashrc ?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, I made phantomjs and casperjs entries into .bashrc similarly as you did and then set cron this way

```
* * * * * source ~/.bashrc; casperjs /var/www/javascript/uat/prime.js 2>&1
```

This worked for me.